# How to implement full text search in fuseki web app deployed on apache tomcat

Tags: jena, fuseki

How to implement full text search in fuseki web app deployed on apache tomcat.
Please describe all the steps.
I am using fuseki-web-app maven version 4.1.0 and apache tomcat 9.

Comment: Documentation for full text search in Apache Jena, including Fuseki:

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html

Comment: In the documentation implementing text-search using fuseki web app is not clearly explained.

Comment: I have deployed fuseki web app war file inside tomcat container and need to implement full-text search in the tomcat setup.